# Android, When reading stored String byte array, it returns different byte array values

Tags: android, string, encryption, arrays

I am trying to store String bytes into a text file, it worked perfectly in my pc but when i try to implement it into my android project it stores it but when i wanna get the string bytes back and convert it into the original bytes it doesnt work. again it worked on my PC, I don't know why it doesn't work on my android project.

CODE:

```
try {
            String y = "Yyyyyyy";
            try {
                File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test/test/newFile.txt");
                if (!file1.createNewFile()) {
                    EncryptedObject a = encryptedMessage.encrypt(y, "test", "test");
                    Log.e("BYTES FROM TEXT1", Arrays.toString(a.getEncryptedBytes()));
                    String example = new String(a.getEncryptedBytes());
                    Log.e("STRINGGGGG", example);
                    BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
                    buffer.write(example);
                    buffer.flush();
                    buffer.close();

                    BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
                    String get_text = "";
                    String lines = null;

                    while ((lines = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
                        get_text += lines; // Gets each line
                    }
                    readFile.close();
                    //THE PROBLEM SEEMS TO START HERE
                    byte[] dec = get_text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                    Log.e("TEXT", get_text);
                    Log.e("BYTES FROM TEXT", Arrays.toString(dec));

                } else {
                    System.out.println("File Already Exist");

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getCause();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

LOGS:

```
04-24 16:41:42.208    2934-2934/com.test.test E/ENCRYPTED TEXT﹕ ϩ{���
04-24 16:41:42.218    2934-2934/com.test.test E/ENCRYPTED TEXT﹕ [-49, -87, 123, -15, 1, -84, -11]
04-24 16:41:42.218    2934-2934/com.test.test E/BYTES FROM TEXT1﹕ [-49, -87, 123, -15, 1, -84, -11]
04-24 16:41:42.218    2934-2934/com.test.test E/STRINGGGGG﹕ ϩ{���
04-24 16:41:42.218    2934-2934/com.test.test E/TEXT﹕ ϩ{���
04-24 16:41:42.218    2934-2934/com.test.test E/BYTES FROM TEXT﹕ [-49, -87, 123, -17, -65, -67, 1, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67]
```

Why is it returning different bytes values? I appreciate any help, thanks.
EDITED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `file` with `file1` at

```
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
```

and

```
new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
try {
    String y = "Yyyyyyy";
    byte[] a = y.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    Log.e("TEXT", y);
    Log.e("BYTES FROM TEXT", Arrays.toString(a));

    try {
        File file1 = new File("test.txt");
        if (file1.createNewFile()) {
            String example = new String(a);

            BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
            buffer.write(example);
            buffer.flush();
            buffer.close();

            BufferedReader readFile= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
            String get_text = "";
            String lines = null;

            while ((lines = readFile.readLine()) != null){
                get_text += lines; // Gets each line
            }

            byte[] dec = get_text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            Log.e("TEXT", get_text);
            Log.e("BYTES FROM TEXT", Arrays.toString(dec));
        } else {
            System.out.println("File Already Exist");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
}
```

My output:

```
TEXT Yyyyyyy
BYTES FROM TEXT [89, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121]
TEXT Yyyyyyy
BYTES FROM TEXT [89, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121]
```

Comment: it worked for normal string, but when i try encrypted messages it doesn't work, but it works on my pc

Answer (score 0):

On major mistake of your code is that you are misuing Strings as byte arrays. 
If you are writing Strings write them directly using a Writer.

Then you can remove the useless conversions like the following:

```
byte[] dec = get_text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

It converts a String to byte[] and then back again to a String.

Consclusion: 
If you want t specify a charset for saving a String use `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` and then write the result in byte[] form to an OutputStream.

Alternatively you can write the String directly charset aware when using an and the constructor `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out,  String charsetName)`

Similar rules apply for reading the file.

Comment: I also tried without doing it with Charset.forName("UTF-8")